# Error retrieving question using a filter that includes question.notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, api-v2.1

I have created a filter to include the `question.notice` field. It seems to be OK as returned by

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/filters/-9xc1l%2Au-JEsf_Q

Then if I want to fetch this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) using the 2.1 API and this freshly created filter,

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/194812?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=-9xc1l%2Au-JEsf_Q

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error_id" : 500,
    "error_name" : "internal_error",
    "error_message":"this error has been logged"
}
```

If I create a filter excluding `question.notice` from the above filter, no more error.

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/194812?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=APXGzZOp5XPM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy, there was a problem selecting the most recent notice for post with multiple notices (which is rare).